# Infinispan custom cache command factory not installed

Tags: hibernate, jpa, caching, wildfly, infinispan

I try to enable second level caching in Hiberante.Im using wildfly 10.0.x.

**Persistent.xml**

```
<persistence-unit name="apidb-persistence-unit"
        transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/DS</jta-data-source>
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
         <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
         <shared-cache-mode>ALL</shared-cache-mode>
..
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>


        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

When I deploy my webapp; im getting following exception;

I have added following two dependencies;

What I'm missing here?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-infinispan</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
    <artifactId>infinispan-core</artifactId>
    <version>8.2.4.Final</version>
</dependency>

16:11:16,835 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."apidb.war#apidb-persistence-unit": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."apidb.war#apidb-persistence-unit": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: apidb-persistence-unit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:179)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:121)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:667)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:193)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: apidb-persistence-unit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:961)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:891)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:161)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheImplementor]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:228)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:483)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:888)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.CacheException: HHH025011: Infinispan custom cache command factory not installed (possibly because the classloader where Infinispan lives couldn't find the Hibernate Infinispan cache provider)
    at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory.getCacheCommandFactory(InfinispanRegionFactory.java:748)
    at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory.startRegion(InfinispanRegionFactory.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory.buildTimestampsRegion(InfinispanRegionFactory.java:390)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CacheImpl.<init>(CacheImpl.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:28)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:20)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:254)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Hmm, maybe the issue was that you were deploying Infinispan inside your application, instead of letting the server plug its own version. All Infinispan dependencies should be marked as `provided`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this like setting only following properties in persistence.xml and edited my standalone.xml.;

**persistence.xml**

```
 <persistence-unit name="apidb-persistence-unit"
            transaction-type="JTA">
            <description>Forge Persistence Unit</description>
            <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
            <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/lobDS</jta-data-source>     
            <shared-cache-mode>ALL</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>

            </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
```

**standalone.xml**

```
<cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query" module="org.hibernate.infinispan:5.2.1.Final">
                <local-cache name="entity">
                    <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="local-query">
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="timestamps"/>
            </cache-container>
```

Comment: In general I don't think there should be a need to change the 2LC cache container configuration. See my suggestion above.